# Single mystery character before a <table>

Tags: html, html-table

At [my website](http://www.nicholaslawson.com) I have a single `<` sign that I want deleted that shows up just before the table and just after the YouTube video.

The thing is, that character does not show up in the `index.html` file. I have checked it in three editors just to be sure. I have no idea where it is coming from.

If you delete the table in Firefox it disappears, but if you delete the YouTube video it does not.  So it has to be linked to the table somehow.

When I look it up as view source selection in Firefox, a small `&lt;` sign shows up to the left side of the table code.  But if you look in the `index.html` file, there's nothing there.

I'm a quasi-intelligent person who can code a site this good but I cannot for the love of all that is electrical squash this bug. Help would be appreciated and it know it's stupid simple to fix. It has to be. I just don't know what I'm missing at this point.

Comment: Paragraphs are your friend. Use them.

Comment: in your index.html are you using < and > around the anchor?

Comment: You should validate your HTML markup - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nicholaslawson.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 250, you have:

```
<<td><a href="http://#"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></a></td>
```

Remove the extra `<` at the start.

This is part of "Album 2", by the way. Anything outside of proper markup in `<table>`s tends to get bumped ahead of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's inside the table, here:

```
<tr>
    <td>Album Two</td>
    <td>Inter5tellar</td>
    <td>A digital song produced in fruity loops for your listening pleasure.</td>
    <<td><a href="http://#"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.oronjo.com/live/next/?fi=80542"><img src = "images/button.jpg"></a></a></td>
    <td>$0.99</td>
</tr>
```

However, since it's not actually inside a `td` (or `th`) tag, browsers cannot render it normally.  Different browsers might do different things, but it seems that Firefox, at least, in effect "pushes" it out of the table and puts it before it instead.

By the way, you might want to run your page through an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/): it has a number of other errors, including a `div` inside the `head` section, duplicate closing tags and some unescaped ampersands in URLs.